# How can I write this if with || , && shorter?

Tags: c#, .net

what if I would have something like this:

```
if (data == null || (data != null && (data.Count() != 3 || data.IsNotCorrect()))
{
  //error...
}
```

The data == null and then || (data != null) part is somehow ugly. Is that how to solve this problem in c#?

Edit:
Sorry! Changed `data.IsCorrect()` to `data.IsNotCorrect()`

Comment: You could simply remove `data!=null&&`. It doesn't change the expression at all.

Comment: Why is `data.IsCorrect()` an error condition?

Comment: Your first check basically *assures* you that if it reaches the `OR` condition that data will not be null so there is no need to check it again - Have a read up on [short-ciruit evalulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right side of `||` gets only evaluated if the left side isn't true (`||` is short-circuiting)

> The conditional-OR operator (`||`) performs a logical-OR of its bool operands. If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to true or false.

*Quoted from [`||` Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (MSDN)*

Apply that to your expression:

```
data == null || (data != null && (data.Count() != 3 || data.IsCorrect())
```

This means when `data != null` is reached, `data` is guaranteed to be different from `null`, and thus `data != null` is guaranteed to be true, and you can leave it out.

Thus your expression is equivalent to:

```
data == null || data.Count() != 3 || data.IsCorrect()
```

Answer (score 8):

Well. `data.Count() != 3 || data.IsCorrect()`. What you are saying is that the data isn't correct if the count is 3. So why the extra if condition instead of doing that check internally?

```
if (data == null || data.IsCorrect())
{
  //error...
}
```

**Update**

Seems to be confusion about what I mean with moving the validating logic to inside the class. All classes should be responsible of determine what's a valid state or not in proper OOP. It's called encapsulation.

This whole idea of letting the caller instead of the class itself determine what's correct or not have emerged more and more since the introduction of OR/Ms, mappers etc etc. But the fact is that classes which doesn't validate their own information is not really properly designed OOP classes. They are just containers like DTOs.

The danger with that is that each and every block of calling code is responsible of making sure that the DTO contains correct and valid information. That means that there are `n` places in your code where a bug can be introduced instead of just `1`.

So that's why I recommend that you move all validation logic to inside the `IsCorrect` or whatever you like to call it. But if you ***really*** want to code according to the basic OOP principles you should not let the class to get in an inconsistent state ever. And that's done as I describe in the blog post below.

http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/06/protect-your-data/

Comment: @ratbum `!data` is not valid in C# unless data is of type bool.  At which point, data cannot be null.

Comment: Oops! I'll get rid of that in case people don't read your comment.

Comment: @cadrell0 `!data` is valid on other types too, if they overload it. Those types can be reference types, and thus be null. It's unlikely that this is the case here, but it's possible in principle. And there is `bool?` which allows both `null` and `!`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Good point about operator overloading.  However, `!` is not valid on `bool?`.  Visual Studio 2010 gives me the following error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)".

Comment: @cadrell0 `!` is valid on `bool?`, but the result is a `bool?`, so you can't use it in an `if` condition directly.

Comment: -1 This makes the assumption that the data is *always* incorrect if the count is 3. What if somewhere else in the program that restriction doesn't apply?

Comment: @NominSim: Why do you make that assumption? The condition can still be applied within the class using the extra conditions. Read about encapsulation. Each class should validate it's on state in proper OOP.

Comment: @Cadrell: Why do you comment `!data` on my answer?

Comment: @jgauffin There was a deleted comment stating the `data == null` could be replaced by `!data`.

Comment: @jgauffin I wasn't making an assumption, I was saying that the assumption that *you* were making may not always be true. The data may be "correct", regardless of its count.

Comment: @NominSim: You made the assumption that I was making an assumption. I simply stated that the `IsCorrect()` method should contain the `Count()` check. And of course together with any other necessary information (if the count may vary). The caller should not decide that.

Comment: @jgauffin You're making the assumption that the data is *not* correct if the `Count() != 3`. I can think of plenty of situations where the "correctness" of the data does not rely *at all* on the Count.

Comment: @NominSim: Aren't you reading what I'm saying? I'm saying that the object ***ITSELF*** should determine what's correct or not. Not the calling code. Read more here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/06/protect-your-data/

Comment: @jgauffin How would you deal with the situation if later the OP had a conditional statement like this: `if(data == null || data.Count() != 4 || data.IsNotCorrect())`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16843/discussion-between-jgauffin-and-nominsim)

Answer (score 7):

You can just leave off the `(data != null && ... )` (i.e. leave the `...` part).

If the argument before `||` evaluates to `true` (i.e. `data` is null), the argument after `||` is not evaluated - so you don't have to worry about null reference exceptions. This is called *short-circuiting*.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the second `data != null` check because of lazy evaluation, and then you no longer need parens because you are left with only `||` operators:

```
if (data == null || data.Count() != 3 || data.IsCorrect())
```

Of course the above is slightly suspect (I would have expected to see `!data.IsCorrect()`).

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the `data != null` part. Since you already gone passed the first part of the statement, you know by that time that data is not null, so no need to check it.

```
if (data == null || (data.Count() != 3 || data.IsCorrect()))
```